# Как изменить цвет окрашенных ячеек datagrid на то , что было сначала

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Проблема заключается в том, что после поиска строка в датагриде окрашивается в определенный цвет и остается такой же при нажатии на эту кнопку, а мне надо чтобы при повторном нажатии высвечивалась другая

Comment: вы нажали на одну кнопку 1 раз и у вас выделилась какая то строка  в datagrid, после этого вы сразу же нажали на эту кнопку еще раз и выделиться должна уже совсем другая строка в datagrid правильно я понял?

Comment: Да я использую эту кнопку для поиска т.е когда пользователь вводит название и нажимает на кнопку выделяется строка с этим названием , а когда пользователь хочет еще раз найти какой-нибудь  другой элемент то выделится та строка и предыдущая и т.д

Comment: Введите переменную, в которой хранится предыдущая найденная строка. При очередном поиске сперва сбрасываете цвет той строки, потом заносите в эту переменную новую строку.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov мне кажется нужно что бы выделялись ВСЕ когда либо найденные строки.  Для этих целей лучше использовать массив `DataGridRow[]`

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < _discoveriesShow.Count; i++)
            {
                if (_discoveriesShow[i].Name == textBoxName.Text)


                    (dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as DataGridRow).Background = Brushes.Yellow;

подскажите пожалуйста как сбросить цвет в таком случае